# Insert different types of data to array - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm new in programming for Android so maybe my question will be very easy to solve but still. 
I'm trying to make an array of different data types : 
I have to add there :

> ```
>  int number
>  string name 
>  int number_2
>  int time
>  int total
> ```

And my question now is how to implement it in easiest way, and how to get data from it.
In case that I have to get a different records for this variables and store it into list . So maibe array in array will be good solution but still - how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap that data in a class and then create an array of that class type. For example

The Class:

```
public class Data {
  public int number;
  public String name;
  public int number_2;
  public int time;
  public int total;
}
```

Then create an array to hold it. (Or use a list, which is more flexible)

```
ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();

Data item = new Data();
item.number = 42;
item.name = "John Doe";
// etc.

dataList.add(item);


// Get some data
Data d = dataList.get(0);
```

Comment: ok that's look pretty nice. Thank you. But what in case that I need to add another record with same datatypes / variables ?

Comment: Then it would be another add, and the new record would be at location 1.

Answer (score 0):

create a `List` of objects:

`List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>()`

then add your objects to it:
`list.add(<your object one by one>);`

once you are done convert it to an array, if an array is a must:

`list.toArray(new Object[list.size()]);`

Comment: can I have String, int, char, .. in the list, without having to cast or any other operation ?

Answer (score 0):

Making a class to store and handle operations on this data is definitely the way to go here:

```
public class MyData
{   
    public int number;
    public int number_2;
    public String name;
    public int time;
    public int total;

   // Add constructor, get, set, as needed.
}
```

And then you can declare and initialise your class:

```
MyData data = new MyData();
```

Or if you want an array of MyData objects:

```
//Creates 10 new MyData objects
MyData[] data = new MyData[10];
```

To learn more about classes and OO concepts in general you can look at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/